# Install multi master kubernetes cluster in local

Tags: kubernetes, local

I have tried with 
minikube tool, It's a single node.
kubeadm tool, It's a multinode but single master.
I am looking for the tool which can be configure multi master kubernetes cluster in 
local.

Comment: If you are running ubuntu you can use canonical kubernetes distribution https://kubernetes.io/docs/getting-started-guides/ubuntu/local/ or  kubeAdm docker in docker https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/kubeadm-dind-cluster

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no tool to install a multi-master Kubernetes cluster locally as of this writing. Generally, a multi-master setup is meant for production environments and a local setup is generally far from what someone would describe as a production environment.

You can probably piece together a local installation from [this](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/independent/high-availability/) and [Kubernetes the Hard Way](https://github.com/kelseyhightower/kubernetes-the-hard-way).

Answer (score 0):

Kubeadm can be used to create a multi-master highly available setup. Documentation regarding this can be found @ https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/production-environment/tools/kubeadm/high-availability/.

If you only have access to one physical machine, but want to create a multi master setup you can use manually provision several VMs and create the cluster, or you can automate everything by using tools such as **Vagrant** and **Ansible Playbooks**. Tutorials regarding this is available @ https://github.com/justmeandopensource/kubernetes/tree/master/kubeadm-ha-multi-master. You can also have a look at justmeandopensource channel on youtube (https://www.youtube.com/user/wenkatn) for detailed tutorials (I used them and was of great help).

Answer (score 0):

if have a limited amount of the **physical** machine and you want to run the setup of **multiple** masters you can use the **LXD container** to first create the VMs and use those VM containers to setup the K8s clusters.

Some of resource link : https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/production-environment/tools/kubeadm/ha-topology/

with kubeadm : https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/production-environment/tools/kubeadm/high-availability/

also as mentioned by @rico kubernetes the hard way is the ultimate thing to use : https://github.com/kelseyhightower/kubernetes-the-hard-way

here one nice tutorial link of youtube using kubeadm: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=q92MYG-EW-w

you can also follow this github opensource repo guide : https://github.com/hub-kubernetes/kubernetes-multi-master